# Zend Framework Filter Input StripTags and "<3"

Tags: zend-framework, filtering

I'm currently using Zend_Filter_StripTags in a commenting system, but stuff kinda breaks when '<3' is entered. StripTags doesn't seem to be smart enough to realize that it's not an HTML tag, and creating the filter as "new Zend_Filter_StripTags(array('3'))" doesn't seem to work either.

Should I pass the input through a regexp first, or is there a way to get Zend_Filter_StripTags to straighten up and fly right?

Comment: Have you considered not filtering, but simply converting potentially harmful characters to HTML entities instead (htmlspecialchars() in PHP)?

Comment: strip_tags() (or its ZF wrapper) is more suited to uses like getting plain text content out of an already-sanitised piece of HTML. For what you're doing (context-sensitive HTML parsing) a fair bit more substantial effort is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up writing a Zend_Filter class that was basically a wrapper for HTMLPurifier. Works perfectly, because HTMLPurifier is a LOT smarter than striptags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Zend much, but if you want stuff like `<3` to be allowed, just do [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead of `strip_tags` on it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Zend_Filter_HtmlEntites most likely.

See: [Zend_Filter_HtmlEnties](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.htmlentities)

Comment: Zend_Filter_HtmlEnties is basically a wrapper for htmlentities, which isn't what I need, because some html ( basic stuff like 'a','b',etc ) need to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with htmlspecialchars and Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities is that if you're trying to strip out all html tags ( like 'a' and 'img', etc ), then instead of stripping them, you end up with that markup in your output.

Take comments on a blog for example. If you use htmlspecialchars or Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities, in a comment where someone tries to use html to enter a link you end up with that markup showing up when you display the comment. But if you use strip_tags or Zend_Filter_StripTags you end up mangling the comment, as neither is smart enough to realize that '<3' isn't a tag, and just strips everything from '<3' until the end of the comment ( or until it finds '>' ).

It would be nice if Zend had something like HTMLPurifier, where it actually checks and validates the input before stripping tags. This means that stuff like '<3' gets left alone, where as stuff like 'Awesome Site' becomes 'Awesome Site'.

This is a problem I'm trying to work around, and at the moment it seems like I'm going to end up writing my own Zend_Filter class that's basically a wrapper for HTMLPurifier.